# Could ramjets be implemented on sub/super-sonic aircraft wings due to the shockwaves generated by them?

Tags: wing, shock-waves, ramjet

Well, I'm a ignorant on aerodynamics and such, but let me explain first:

In [this video](https://youtu.be/SFBvM5iVHY8?t=70) (it could be just a video, but) it is said that wings are angled backwards to avoid supersonic shock waves generated by the the shape of the wings.

Therefore, in my ignorant perspective, it seems that this type of occurrence would allow for a ramjet to work on subsonic speeds, since the airflow that would theoretically hit them would already achieve supersonic speeds.

I think ramjets are a really fuel-hunger type of turbine, but nevertheless, I can't stop put wonder if this can be efficiently be applied in any way (even if the wing shape isn't being applied through the entire wing, but in a specific point where the ramjet would be placed).

Comment: What do you mean by your third paragraph?  It seems like it contradicts itself - i.e. how could a ramjet work at subsonic speeds if the airflow is supersonic?

Comment: @MichaelHall In high subsonic flight, there are portions of the airflow around a wing that can achieve supersonic velocities. So it's not unreasonable to ask if the same could happen at an air intake.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield, I know that, and the way you stated it makes complete sense.  But if that is what the OP is saying in this section it isn't worded very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of the shape of the wing, ramjets only outperform turbojets at supersonic airspeed. Ramjets work because the speed of the incoming airflow is such that there is no rotating compressor/turbine required for keeping the jet thrust going. So *"I think ramjets are a really fuel-hunger type of turbine.."* is a misconception, ramjets have no turbine.

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramjet) shows how they are constructed, and mentions that they are sometimes called flying stovepipes - the incoming air is slowed down to a slow crawl, and thereby compressed so much that fuel can be injected directly in the high-pressure area to obtain the trust necessary to keep the air flowing into the inlet. Ramjets really work well at speeds between Mach 3 and Mach 6 according to the wiki.

[image: Prof. Wittenberg, Propulsion Of Aircraft, TU Delft]

How the incoming air is compressed is important for the efficiency of the cycle. Supersonic shockwaves come with a loss in total pressure $p_t$, with oblique shockwaves yielding smaller losses than a normal shockwave. The pic above (from prof. Wittenberg's course handout that I hung on to) shows a Spike Inlet like in the wiki plot in design state, this one with 1 oblique and 1 normal shock. Pic below shows that a simple pitot inlet has large losses above about M = 1.5, adding more oblique shocks adds efficiency.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the Wikipedia article on [ramjets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramjet), we have:

> Although ramjets have been run as slow as 45 metres per second (160
> km/h), below about Mach 0.5 (170 m/s; 610 km/h) they give little
> thrust and are highly inefficient due to their low pressure ratios.

So supersonic speed is not necessary for ramjets to work, although

> Due to the stoichiometric combustion temperature, efficiency is
> usually good at high speeds (around Mach 2–Mach 3, 680–1,000 m/s,
> 2,500–3,700 km/h), whereas at low speeds the relatively poor pressure
> ratio means the ramjets are outperformed by turbojets, or even
> rockets.